# How to determine which grant type was used for an access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have an API configured in WSO2 API Manager that allows multiple different OAuth 2.0 grant types (client credentials and openid).

My API requires a different behavior depending on whether it was called via an access_token generated by client credentials vs openid. How can the API verify whether this access token provided was generated via client credentials or openid?

**Edit and Solution**:

I have found a way to do this. The following [WSO2 Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT) shows how to configure the API Manager to pass a JWT that includes some token specific information. In that token you will find the "http://wso2.org/claims/usertype" claim. If your api is being accessed via client credentials grant type its value will be APPLICATION if its being accessed via openid or SAML it will be APPLICATION_USER. I haven't found documentation that specifically outlines this scenario but it seems to work.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's a direct way of doing this unless you [write your own code](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Writing+Custom+Handlers) to get this information from `IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN` table.

But using some hacky way you should be able to do this without much effort.

For example,

1) In case of you already knowing the application creator's name (or a userstore domain), you can get the owner of the token as mentioned in [this blog post](http://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2016/08/wso2-api-manager-how-to-retrieve.html) and compare it with the application owner's name. The owner of the tokens which are generated by client-credentials grant type is always the same as the application owner. However this methods has a limitation that you can't differenciate when application owner calls the with API OICD token and client credentials grant type.

2) Enable [JWT tokens](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT) and then take your decision based on user claims.